# Boost::any not empty when used from a pointer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I have the following test application:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void check(boost::any y)
{
    if (y.empty())
        std::cout << "empty!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not empty, type: " << y.type().name() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    boost::any boostAny;
    check(boostAny);

    boost::any* boostAny2 = &boostAny;
    check(boostAny2);

    boost::any* boostAny3 = new boost::any;
    check(boostAny3);
    delete(boostAny3);
}
```

I compile and run like so:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp && ./test
```

Output is:

```
empty!
Not empty, type: PN5boost3anyE
Not empty, type: PN5boost3anyE
```

I would expect for all 3 tests the same output. But it's not. Why? Is this a bug? Tried with boost 1.54.0 and 1.55.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boostAny2` is a pointer to `boost::any`. You pass it as parameter to `check`, which expects a `boos::any`, so a new `boost::any` instance is created from the `boost::any*` (ie. the value type will be `boost::any*`). Ref. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/any.html

Or in other words, what's actually happening is (conceptually) :

```
boost::any* boostAny2 = &boostAny;
boost::any param = boost::any(boostAny2); // contruct a new boost::any instance from the pointer boostAny2
check(param);
```

Maybe you meant instead :

```
check(*boostAny2);
```

The same applies to `boostAny3`.

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly constructing `any` objects containing the pointers you supplied, so obviously they aren't empty.

Your code

```
check(boostAny3);
```

is equivalent to this code

```
check(any(boostAny3));
```

I think what you want instead is

```
check(*boostAny3);
```